# How to use .xacro file for spawning model by using spawn_model service in c++

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I have a question about spawning model by using spawn_model service. I use .xacro file for descripting the hector_quadrotor model. And I need to dynamically spawning new model by calling spawn_model service. But I feel confused about how to use .xacro file as parameter for the model_xml fild of gazebo_msgs/SpawnModel message type.If conversion is necessary, does anyone know how to conver .xacro to .urdf or .xml in c++ code.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259905/how-to-use-.xacro-file-for-spawning-model-by-using-spawn_model-service-in-c++/) by [jasonwang538@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/30092/jasonwang538@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Xacro files need to be parsed by the [xacro parser](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) before you can load them into Gazebo, rViz, etc.

When you are running things through a launch file, you can do this easily at launch time, like the example below. But if you are using the file from a node, it's easier to run xacro first to produce an output that you save to a file and work with that processed file.

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find my_robot_description)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro' "/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0